# Get how many days/hours/seconds ago from date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date in this format:

`2019-04-23T19:03:34Z`

How can I convert this to `x days ago` in jquery/javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct two Date objects and calculate the difference between them.
From the result - which is in milliseconds - you can calculate the time in days with some simple math.

```js
var old = new Date("2019-04-23T19:03:34Z")
var today = new Date();
console.log(Math.floor((today - old) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24) + " day(s) ago");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) which is a very powerful javascript library for working with dates, and it works in node.js and the browser. You can simply do `moment(date).from(moment(new Date()))` and it will already format it for you as a string, with proper grammar, i.e., "a day ago", "two days ago", "three days ago", etc.